# How can I maximize mmap performance?

Tags: linux, optimization, mmap

I'm using `mmap` to read/write a file that I'm using in a database-like way. The file is much larger than available RAM. My use case is single-process, multi-threaded. How can I maximize the performance of accessing the mmap'd memory?

I'm assuming I should use `MAP_PRIVATE` rather than `MAP_SHARED` to take advantage of copy-on-write.

Is there any performance advantage to using `MAP_POPULATE` and/or `MAP_NONBLOCK`?

Are there any other performance-related things I should consider when using mmap?

Comment: If you want to read *and write* the file, don't use `MAP_PRIVATE` as your writes will not affect the file.

Answer (score 3):

`mmap` manipulates process' virtual address space and the [PTEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table) in the CPU and RAM, and that is not a cheap operation.

Linus Torvalds replied a number of times on drawbacks of `mmap`:

- https://yarchive.net/comp/mmap.html#6
- https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/zero-copy.html#9

One way to minimize `mmap` cost is keep mapping files (or parts of them) into the same virtual address space range, so that no PTE manipulation is necessary.

`mmap` without `MAP_POPULATE` reserves the virtual address space in the process, but doesn't back it with hardware memory pages, so that the thread raises a page fault hardware interrupt when accessing that page for the 1st time, and the kernel handles that interrupt by mapping the actual hardware memory page. `MAP_POPULATE` allows you to avoid those page-faults, but it may take longer to return from `mmap`.

`MAP_LOCKED` makes sure that the page doesn't get swapped out.

You may also like to experiment with `MAP_HUGETLB` and one of `MAP_HUGE_2MB, MAP_HUGE_1GB` flags. If suitable for your application, huge pages minimize the number of [TLB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer) misses.

Try binding threads to the same NUMA node with `numactl` to make sure that threads only access local NUMA memory. E.g. `numactl --membind=0 --cpunodebind=0 <app>`.

`MAP_PRIVATE` vs `MAP_SHARED` only matters if you'd like to modify the mapped pages. `MAP_PRIVATE` doesn't propagate your modification to the file or other processes' mappings of that file.